# What is a sample format?

Tags: c++, audio, core-audio, portaudio

I'm currently looking at PortAudio code samples, especially the [paex_record.c](https://github.com/EddieRingle/portaudio/blob/master/examples/paex_record.c) one.

In the preprocessor directives, which looks old fashioned, there is a `typedef PaSampleType` which takes a `PaSampleFormat` value defined in `portaudio.h`

I know what a sample rate is, but I don't know what a sample format is.

In the header file, it is defined as

```
  /** The sample format of the buffer provided to the stream callback,
     a_ReadStream() or Pa_WriteStream(). It may be any of the formats described
     by the PaSampleFormat enumeration.
    */
```

But it doens't make thing clearer for me.

I would really appreciate if someone could shed some light on this concept and how it applies to my case.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

From portaudio.h:

```
typedef unsigned long PaSampleFormat;  
#define paFloat32        ((PaSampleFormat) 0x00000001) 
#define paInt32          ((PaSampleFormat) 0x00000002) 
#define paInt24          ((PaSampleFormat) 0x00000004) 
#define paInt16          ((PaSampleFormat) 0x00000008) 
#define paInt8           ((PaSampleFormat) 0x00000010) 
#define paUInt8          ((PaSampleFormat) 0x00000020) 
#define paCustomFormat   ((PaSampleFormat) 0x00010000) 
#define paNonInterleaved ((PaSampleFormat) 0x80000000)
```

It looks like the portaudio library uses PaSampleFormat as a bitfield that represents different sample formats.  So if you want to work with interleaved floats, you would do this:

```
 PaSampleFormat myFormat = paFloat32;
```

Or if you wanted to work with non-interleaved signed shorts you would do this:

```
 PaSampleFormat myFormat = paInt16 | paNonInterleaved;
```

Then, the library has a number of functions that take a PaSampleFormat as an argument so that the functions know how to process the samples internally. Here's another excerpt from the library that uses this bitfield to get the sample size.

```
PaError Pa_GetSampleSize( PaSampleFormat format )
{
    int result;

    PA_LOGAPI_ENTER_PARAMS( "Pa_GetSampleSize" );
    PA_LOGAPI(("\tPaSampleFormat format: %d\n", format ));

    switch( format & ~paNonInterleaved )
    {

    case paUInt8:
    case paInt8:
        result = 1;
        break;

    case paInt16:
        result = 2;
        break;

    case paInt24:
        result = 3;
        break;

    case paFloat32:
    case paInt32:
        result = 4;
        break;

    default:
        result = paSampleFormatNotSupported;
        break;
    }

    PA_LOGAPI_EXIT_PAERROR_OR_T_RESULT( "Pa_GetSampleSize", "int: %d", result );

    return (PaError) result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

PortAudio provides samples in raw PCM format. That means each sample is an amplitude to be given to the DAC (digital-to-analog converter) in your sound card. For `paInt16`, this is a value from -32768 to 32767. For `paFloat32`, this is a floating-point value from -1.0 to 1.0. The sound card converts this values to a proportional voltage that then drives your audio equipment.